# Standard Error, Standard Deviation and Variance confusion

Tags: regression, standard-error

I am quite confused in these terminologies (especially but not limited to regression)

 I do understand what Variance and Standard Deviation means, they measure the dispersion / variability of the data.

However, according to my understanding, Standard Error $= \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$ where s is the sample standard deviation.

 But in regression (for simplicity, here refer to Simple Linear Regression but MLR shall be of the same fashion) $y = \beta_0 + \beta_{1}x + e$.

 Variance of $\hat\beta_1$ = $\frac{\sigma^2}{SXX}$

 And while we are doing confidence interval for $\hat\beta_1$, the SE we use is simply the square root of Var($\hat\beta_1$) = $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{SXX}}$ without needing to divide by $\sqrt{n}$

My questions:

 1) Is there a difference between normal Standard Error (of mean) that we talk about (i.e. $\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$) and the SE we talk in regression.

 2) I suppose, $\hat\beta_1$ is not a mean but purely an estimator of the parameter $\beta_1$, so why do we use SE when we are constructing confidence interval of $\hat\beta_1$?

 3) What about confidence interval for predicted $y$ value and fitted $y$ value respectively?

Comment: Whenever you speak of the standard deviation of an _estimator_ that is a _standard error._ For example $\bar X$ is an estimator of $\mu$ so $SD(\bar X) = SE(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{n}.$  Often, if $\sigma$ is unknown and estimated by $S$ authors say that the 'standard error' of $\bar X$ is $S/\sqrt{n}$ when more fastidious terminology would be '_estimated_ standard error'. (The word _estimated_ gets dropped, usually with no harm, because one knows $S$ is an estimate.)

Answer (score 8):

The term "standard error" refers to the standard deviation of a statistic that is calculated. So, you can calculate a standard error for a mean--because the mean is a statistic. You can also calculate a standard error for a parameter estimate like $\hat{\beta}$.

We say standard error instead of standard deviation to distinguish between a value that's calculated from repeated observations and an estimate that's based on a theory about the distribution.

We only have one observation for $\hat{\beta}$, and we have mathematical theory to derive its sampling error--so we call that the *standard error*.

We have more than one observation of a variable X, and we calculate the sampling error based on that observed data--so we call that statistic the *standard deviation*.

Comment: so the formula $\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$ is just the formula for standard error of the mean ($\bar{x}$)

Comment: and the difference between standard deviation and standard error is the number of observations. If the data is a statistic, which has only one observation, summarizing a bunch of data point (like the mean summarize the whole set of data) then it will be called standard error. While if it is a lot of observations (like the set of data itself), then it will be the standard deviation?

Comment: Yes--That's the gist of the reasoning behind having two different terms for what looks like the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The terminology is the same everywhere in statistics I think:

- [Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) $\sigma^2$ is the second moment of a known probability distribution
- [Standard Deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) $\sigma$ is the square root of variance
- [Variance of the mean](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/sampling_distributions/samp_dist_mean.html) $\sigma^2_{\mu} = \frac{\sigma^2}{N}$ is the variance of the mean of $N$ i.i.d random variables
- Standard Deviation of the Mean $\sigma_{\mu}$ is the square root of the variance of the mean

The 4 above metrics apply analytically to probability distributions. One can estimate any one of them, typically denoted by letter $s$ and prefix 'sample', such as 'sample error of the mean' $s_{\mu}$. Sample standard deviation and Sample standard deviation of the mean are also known as [Standard Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error) and Standard Error of the mean (SEM) respectively

With respect to your questions:

- Variance and standard deviation are metrics of the distribution of the random variables in analytic case and a metric of data in the sample case. These terms are not applicable to parameters of your model, such as $\beta$ or $\hat \beta$. These are simply the parameter and its estimate.
- When you construct a [confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) for an unknown
  parameter, you perform a hypothesis test. The confidence interval is likely to be a function of the moments of the distribution, or their sample counterparts, but that depends strongly on the underlying distribution.
- Confidence intervals only apply to unknown parameters of the model, they do not apply to parts of data such as $y$. The closest entity to a confidence interval when applied to random variable itself is a [tolerance interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolerance_interval), namely, the interval where the random variable is likely to fall given the exact model parameters

Comment: Standard deviation and standard error are not the same thing.

Comment: @Eoin I will correct, no need to rush with minuses :). I am used to people using the termis interchangingly

Comment: @Eoin Is it correct now?